# How do i put a desktop application installer on a webpage so users can download my software?

Tags: distribution, setup.py

I apologize if this isn't the proper usage of Stackoverflow, but i have no experience distributing software, so I'm looking for the proper direction to move in.

Basically, I'm building a mini HPC cloud computing platform for running tasks in parallel to speed up processing time. I am having no difficulty connecting the application to my servers so users can upload packages || run the packages || pull the data back onto their computers etc. However, i believe most users would prefer to use a desktop application instead of going through their web browser.

The application that connects to my servers is written in python, so i briefly looked at the "setup.py" script for packaging || distributing packages, but I don't know if that's what i need. I simply want users to navigate to a website, click the download button, and have the application download onto their system, tucked away in a spot that they won't touch (in the background somewhere). I suppose I could put a link to an executable script on the webpage with personalized code that copies the package over when clicked, but some web services don't support ".exe" scripts from running (or i could bypass that by hosting the website on my own computer?). But is that the easiest method? Do I need to use a "setup.py" script for linux users to properly install the service on their systems? I'm pretty lost with the whole distribution aspect of programming; everything I learned was from recreational coding, never from a formal education. I understand that I should research topics on my own, but I don't want to wander in the wrong direction. Any information that can help point me in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Also, assume that i know nothing about writing html || css. I can understand the languages because I've scraped websites before, but I'm definitely not building websites as a hobby.

Comment: *"navigate to a website, click the download button, and have the application download onto their system, tucked away in a spot that they won't touch"* – Well, that's not gonna happen. Downloads done through a web browser will never tuck themselves into invisible corners, since that would be a big security problem. The user will be able to *download* a file from your site, yes, but then they will need to do something with it explicitly to "install" it.

Comment: Yes, but running a script can "install" it, no? Assume I have no knowledge of the subject.  Many applications move into the hidden folders, and give you an application to use -- but that's not important. How do i allow the user to explicitly "install" it. That's what i want them to do; i just never learned how to handle that. I saw a hacker (instructor) put an ".exe" file in a browser that explicitly asked the user to download the script. Does the installer need JavaScript code to order the download? Will that happen automatically? I apologize for the ignorance; I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: You'd package your app in an "installer". That's an executable file which the user will need to explicitly run which will move the files into the necessary folders and/or do anything else that's necessary to install the app. There are many different ways to write installers and they'll need to be specific to the targeted OS, so there's no generic advice anyone can give how to write an installer.

Comment: Okay, so they click the installer in the browser. It runs, I assume from JavaScript code (I can figure that out), then it installs. I know how to write an installer; I just didn't know if i needed to write it myself, or if there was another way of just plugging in the details. Do most web hosting sites block installers? I know they don't get blocked if I host the website myself, but I don't personally build websites, so using wordpress would be the easier option.